# Extensors in mathematics and in physics

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus, definition, mathematics

Could someone explain in a simple but accurate manner what [extensors](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=extensor+mathematics) are as mathematical entities and how they are used?

How do extensors essentially differ from tensors?

Are there or could there be applications of extensors in physics?

Some related papers about the topic of extensors:

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501558

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703090

Comment: This appears to be a rather broad request, especially the "applications in physics" part, which is generally looked down upon as it's really asking for a list instead of an explanation.